# How to use math.sqrt for DStream[(Double,Double)]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

For the streaming data `DStream[(Double, Double)]`, how do I estimate the root mean squared error? See my code below. The line `math.sqrt(summse)` is where I have a problem (the code does not compile):

```
  def calculateRMSE(output: DStream[(Double, Double)], n: DStream[Long]): Double = {
        val summse = output.foreachRDD { rdd =>
          rdd.map {
              case pair: (Double, Double) =>
                val err = math.abs(pair._1 - pair._2);
                err*err
          }.reduce(_ + _)
        }
        math.sqrt(summse)
  }
```

UPDATE:
The code doesn't compile: `Cannot resolve reference sqrt with such signature. Expected: Double, Actual: Unit`

Comment: So what is your problem? Doesn't compile, runtime faults or wrong value?

Comment: @thoredge: The code doesn't compile: `Cannot resolve reference sqrt with such signature. Expected: Double, Actual: Unit`

Comment: What do you want to do? calculateRMSE of a DStream, at what point in time? DStreams are infinite streams, so you cannot expect to execute an operation `f(DStream)` and obtain a scalar value out of it, because the result will be dependent of time.

Answer (score 1):

The method foreachRDD(...) returns unit so that is expected. According to the docs the result is written back to the this (output) DStream. I guess it's that you'll have to apply sqrt to.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you exactly mean. Could you add an example please? How to apply sqrt to output inside the given function? (obviously it shouldn't be `math.sqrt(output)`)

Comment: @Klue add a type annotation to your `summse` and it should become clear. `math.sqrt` requires a `Double`