# How to solve Type mismatch issue (expected: Double, actual: Unit)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, dstream

Here is my function that calculates root mean squared error. However the last line cannot be compiled because of the error `Type mismatch issue (expected: Double, actual: Unit)`. I tried many different ways to solve this issue, but still without success. Any ideas?

```
  def calculateRMSE(output: DStream[(Double, Double)]): Double = {
        val summse = output.foreachRDD { rdd =>
          rdd.map {
              case pair: (Double, Double) =>
                val err = math.abs(pair._1 - pair._2);
                err*err
          }.reduce(_ + _)
        }
        // math.sqrt(summse)  HOW TO APPLY SQRT HERE?
  }
```

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: I want to calculate root mean squared error for the streaming data. Maybe the way I try to approach this task is incorrect. If so, I'd like to know the correct way, assuming the the input data is of the type `DStream[(Double,Double)]`.

Comment: I'm still not sure of what is it you are doing.

Comment: @eliasah: DStream contains pairs of Double, e.g. ((5.0, 5.2), (5.1, 5.15)...) Assume that the first element in the pair is an actual value, while the second element is a predicted value. What I need to do is to calculate an error between actual and predicted values, using Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) metric. When I get new data in streaming, RMSE should obviously change (i.e. it should be recalculated using my function `calculateRMSE`). Is it impossible to do this?

Comment: and what do you want to do with this RMSE ? foreachRDD doesn't return any value

Comment: @eliasah: I found the solution using `RegressionMetrics` library

Comment: This is basically the same as your earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978409/how-to-use-math-sqrt-for-dstreamdouble-double.  But as @eliasah says, you're iterating over each RDD, then throwing the result of the calculation away, as foreach doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As eliasah pointed out, `foreach` (and `foreachRDD`) don't return a value; they are for side-effects only. If you wanted to return something, you need `map`. Based off your second solution:

```
val rmse = output.map(rdd => new RegressionMetrics(rdd).rootMeanSquaredError)
```

It looks better if you make a little function for it:

```
val getRmse = (rdd: RDD) => new RegressionMetrics(rdd).rootMeanSquaredError

val rmse = output.map(getRmse)
```

Ignoring empty RDDs,

```
val rmse = output.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(getRmse)
```

Here is the exact same sequence as a for-comprehension. It's just syntactic sugar for map, flatMap and filter, but I thought it was much easier to understand when I was first learning Scala:

```
val rmse = for {
  rdd <- output
  if (rdd.nonEmpty)
} yield new RegressionMetrics(rdd).rootMeanSquaredError
```

And here's a function summing the errors, like your first attempt:

```
def calculateRmse(output: DStream[(Double, Double)]): Double = {

val getRmse = (rdd: RDD) => new RegressionMetrics(rdd).rootMeanSquaredError

output.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(getRmse).reduce(_+_)
}
```

The compiler's complaint about `nonEmpty` is actually an issue with DStream's `filter` method. Instead of operating on the RDDs in the DStream, `filter` is operating on the pairs of doubles `(Double, Double)` given by your DStream's type parameter.

I don't know enough about Spark to say it's a *flaw*, but it is very strange. `Filter` and most other operations over collections are typically [defined in terms of foreach](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/trait-traversable), but DStream implements those functions without following the same convention; its deprecated method `foreach` and current `foreachRDD` both operate over the stream's RDDs, but [its other higher-order methods don't](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream).

So my method won't work. DStream probably has a good reason for being weird (performance related?) Here's probably bad way to do it with `foreach`:

```
def calculateRmse(ds: DStream[(Double, Double)]): Double = {

  var totalError: Double = 0

  def getRmse(rdd:RDD[(Double, Double)]): Double = new RegressionMetrics(rdd).rootMeanSquaredError

  ds.foreachRDD((rdd:RDD[(Double, Double)]) => if (!rdd.isEmpty) totalError += getRmse(rdd))

  totalError
}
```

But it works!

Comment: Thanks. The function `calculateRMSE` does not compile - it says `Cannot resolve symbol rdd, + and nonEmpty`. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: In case of `nonEmpty` it also says `Type mismatch, expected ((Double,Double))=>Boolean, actual ((Double,Double))=>Any`.

Comment: Whoops. I made a mistake in `getRmse`, parentheses should have been around the left half of the function only. But the problems with `rdd` and `+` are slightly worse. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this task as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics

output.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  if (!rdd.isEmpty)
    {
      val metrics = new RegressionMetrics(rdd)
      val rmse = metrics.rootMeanSquaredError
      println("RMSE: " + rmse)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I hope so:) `foreachRDD` does not return any value. I though I should accumulate MSE over different RDDs and then estimate RMSE. But the approach is different, as shown in the answer.

Comment: you are still not doing anything with the RMSE except printing it