# Type mismatch, expected ((Double,Double))=>Boolean, actual ((Double,Double))=>Any

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following two functions that do not compile due to 3 errors:

1. `RegressionMetrics`: `Cannot resolve constructor`
2. `_.nonEmpty`: `Type mismatch, expected ((Double,Double))=>Boolean,
       actual ((Double,Double))=>Any`
   [image]
3. `reduce(_+_)`: `Cannot resolve symbol +`.

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics

//..

def getRMSE (rdd: RDD): Double = {
    val metrics = new RegressionMetrics(rdd)
    metrics.rootMeanSquaredError
}

def calculateRMSE(output: DStream[(Double, Double)]): Double = {
    output.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(getRMSE).reduce(_+_)
}

test("Test1") {
// do some data preprocessing
// call the function calculateRMSE
}
```

Any idea how to fix these errors?

P.S: The strange thing is that when I put `val metrics = new RegressionMetrics(rdd)` inside the `test` is compiles without any problem.

UPDATE:

I was able to solve issue #1 by adding `(Double,Double)` to `RDD`:

```
  def getRMSE(rdd : RDD[(Double, Double)]) : Double = {
    val metrics = new RegressionMetrics(rdd)
    metrics.rootMeanSquaredError
  }
```

Comment: Split this line ` output.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(getRMSE).reduce(_+_)` into a sequence of `val` assignments (`val filtered = output.filter(...); val mapped = filtered.map(...); val reduced = mapped.reduce(...)` and look at the types. I think you'll find they're not what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

> [reduce(func)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transformations-on-dstreams):
>   Return a new DStream of single-element RDDs by
>   aggregating the elements in each RDD of the source DStream using a
>   function func (which takes two arguments and returns one). The
>   function should be associative so that it can be computed in parallel.

So, right signature for calculateRMSE should be:

```
def calculateRMSE(output: DStream[(Double, Double)]): DStream[Double]
```

Comment: I tried what you say. The problem is the same. See my update, I posted the screenshot.

Comment: you can't call nonEmpty on tuple of double, is what your screenshot saying. what do you want to achieve by this filtering?

Comment: My question refers to the answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984923/how-to-solve-type-mismatch-issue-expected-double-actual-unit
As I understood by using `filter` I can filter out empty RDDs...